# Mostrar informação quando não há dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz um `if`, caso venha alguma coisa de retorno, então ele monta uma página, senão ele deveria esconder tudo e mostrar uma mensagem. Não é um alert, mas sim, uma mensagem na página mesmo. No meu else eu apenas escondo uma div e um form. Isso tá ok. Só não sei como fazer para gerar uma mensagem, tipo um `<h1>Mensagem</h1>`, tipo isso, não necessariamente isso, mas algo parecido. Veja o meu `else` como está:

```
else
{
     $("#selecionarHotel").css("display","none");
     $("#filtroPesquisa").prop("hidden", true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Em Razor, você pode fazer o seguinte na sua *View*:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0) {
    // Seu código
} else {
    <div>Não há registros a serem exibidos.</div>
}
```

Para que isso seja viável você deve ter uma `Model` aplicada à sua view. Por exemplo:

```
@model IEnumerable<Caminho.Da.Minha.Classe>
```

Comment: Não consigo pegar o Count da Model. Ele não existe.

Comment: Você pode colocar **na pergunta** o código completo da sua *View*?

Comment: a view é muito grande, mas posso colocar o objeto Model que a minha view carrega.

Comment: Pode ser só o cabeçalho da *View*. Preciso saber como você envia a informação para a *View* para editar minha resposta.

Comment: @pnet cara, você precisa se acostumar a usar o SOPT como se deve... O pessoal anda reclamando bastante do seu uso do site porque você não escolhe as respostas que resolvam seu problema, nem fornece perguntas com subsídios suficientes. Nos ajude a manter o alto nível dessa comunidade

Comment: Se você definiu um `@Model` como `IEnumerable`, `Count` **tem** que existir

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que os dados estejam chegando em sua `View` de forma assíncrona. Neste caso, você pode ter uma estrutura `html` pronta para exibir essa mensagem e mante-la em uma classe `css` que oculte. Caso seu `Model` venha vazio, você pode implementar uma rotina `javascript` para exibi-la, vamos a um exemplo:

no seu css

```
.no-data {
   display: none;
}
```

em seu html, você poderia manter uma `div` com sua mensagem aplicando o css que oculta:

```
<div id="mensagem" class="no-data">Nenhuma registro encontrado.</div>
```

e para exibir, no seu javascript:

```
$("#mensagem").show();
```

Se os dados em sua `View` vêem diretamente no `Model`, sendo assim, você pode implementar essa rotina no lado do servidor para gerar o html, exemplo:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0) 
{
    // sua exibição aqui...
} 
else 
{
    <div>Nenhuma registro encontrado.</div>
}
```